# How to parse JSON string in iPad Apps?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to convert the image in my database to retrieve it in my iAd apps and in order to do so i am using JSON ,but I am not getting it done properly.

Inside my button onTouch i have written this code

```
//create string contain url address for php file, the file name is phpFile.php,it receives parameter :name 
NSString *strURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"....my.php","hhhhh"];

//to execute php code
NSData *dataURL=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]]; 

//to receive the returned Result 
NSString *strResult = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]self]; 
NSLog(@"%@",strResult);
```

Comment: Could you detail what you have tried and your code?

Comment: Inside my button onTouch i have written this code 
    //create string contain url address for php file, the file name is phpFile.php,it receives parameter :name
    NSString *strURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.....my.php","hhhhh"];
    
    //to execute php code
    NSData *dataURL=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
    
    //to receive the returned Result
    NSString *strResult = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]self];
   NSLog(@"%@",strResult);

Comment: i want to parse this and get all details from above string and then display all these in my app

Comment: Try this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638629/how-to-parse-json-format-in-objective-c

Comment: @deanWombourne: the answers to that qquestion are out of date.  iOS5 adds its own JSON parser.

Comment: He didn't specify iOS5 only but a fair point :)

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways of doing this:

1. If you deployment target is iOS 5.0 and up you could use: [NSJSonSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
2. if you want to support versions below 5.0 you could use one of many libraries to do that, personally I find [SBJson](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/) quite good. Take a look at this snippet to get an idea :

   ```
   NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   NSDictionary *dic = [dataString JSONValue];
   NSArray * element = [dic objectForKey:@"jsonKey"];
   NSString * someSimpleElement = [dic objectForKey:@"jsonKey"];
   ```

Comment: yep! i am using ios 5 as my targeted device can somebody elaborate the NSSerialization & respective coding???

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting iOS 5 or later, you can use the [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.

```
NSError& anError = nil;
id foo = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: dataURL options: 0 error: &anError];
if (foo == nil)
{
    // handle the error
}
else
{
    //play with the returned object
}
```

If you need to target an earlier version of iOS, you'll need SBJSON or TouchJSON or similar, but the princiiple is the same.

NB please also read the [URL loading guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i), your current code loads the data from the server synchronously.  If this is the main thread, the UI will freeze until you have got the data or the connection times out.

Comment: in my Json folder its showing error in all .m files release is unavailable how to resolve these error

Comment: yep! i am using ios 5 as my targeted device can somebody elaborate the NSSerialization & respective coding???

Comment: I can't elaborate on `NSJSONSerialization` because this really is pretty much all there is to it.